# How do you properly create a function in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, slider

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this Jquery function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function Slider(){
    $("#dv_slider #img1").show("fade",500);
  }
});
```

I don't think the problem comes from my HTML or CSS. Also, when I get rid of the "Slider" function is seems to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dv_slider #img1").show("fade",500);
});
```

The problem is I do need to use functions to make more complex effects. In this case I'm trying to create a slider.

Comment: Where you call Slider() function in first example?

Comment: You have to call the function Slider()

Comment: If you were coming to say that "the second snippet is working but i am not sure how to call it via a function". Then seriously...   :|

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your first option, but you are just declaring the function `Slider()`, then to run it you need to actually call the function. You also can declare the functions outside the document ready

```
function Slider(){
  $("#dv_slider #img1").show("fade",500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  Slider();
 });
```

In the second option you are just running a statement that is executed right away.